# Automorphic number - Java program

Tags: java, string, numbers

I'm working on code which checks if a number is special in some way, such as being a prime number, a Kaprekar number, an automorphic number etc. I've worked on the automorphic part of it:

```
import java.io.*;
class automorphic
{
    public static void main(String ags[])throws IOException
    {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        System.out.println("Enter a number.");
        int num = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        int sq = num*num;
        String number = Integer.toString(sq);
        int l = number.length();
        int x = l-1;
        String s = number.substring(x);
        int no = Integer.parseInt(s);

        if(no == num)
            System.out.println("Automorphic number.");
        else
            System.out.println("Not an automorphic number.");
    }
}
```

The code compiles fine, and the execution is also fine. But, there is a logical error. If you enter the number 25 when prompted for input, the screen says that it is not an automorphic number, whereas it actually is. How do I resolve this?
TIA.

Comment: By doing some debugging.

Comment: BTW, an automorphic number is a number, which when squared, holds the number itself in its last two digits. Example: 25 x 25 = 625. The last two digits of 625 holds the number 25.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth In which part?

Comment: int x = l-1; should be  int x = l-(length of first number);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You check if the last digit of the squared number is equal to the original number, which only works for single digit numbers.

You need to replace

```
String s = number.substring(x);
```

with

```
String s = number.substring(number.length-Integer.toString(num).length());
```

`Integer.toString(num).length()` is the number of digits of the original number, and `number.substring(number.length-Integer.toString(num).length())` would give you the last `Integer.toString(num).length()` digits of the squared number.

Answer (score 0):

```
static boolean isAutomorphic(int number)
{
    final int squared = number * number;

    return squared % 100 == number % 100;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may find it much easier going forward if you refactor and break the is Automorphic check into a new function and do something like this:

```
import java.io.*;

public class Automorphic {
    public static void main(String ags[])throws IOException
    {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        System.out.println("Enter a number.");
        int num = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        if (isAutomorphic(num)) {
            System.out.println("Automorphic number.");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Not an automorphic number.");   
        }
    }

    public static boolean isAutomorphic(int number) {
        return ("" + number * number).endsWith("" + number);
    }
}
```

Much easier to extend as well...